# Metrics collection of application behind Citrix

Tags: powershell, loadrunner, citrix, wql, sitescope

I need to measure .NET performance counters using Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) during performance test.

Testing platform is based on LoadRunner and SiteScope.

I have use the follow approach:

1. using perfmon application to identify .NET counters that I need to monitor at '_Global_' scope
2. using wbemtest application to translate counters in WMI object and elaborate required Windows Management Instrumentation Query Language (WQL) queries
3. translate counters extraction process in functional routine with PowerShell using Get-WmiObject cmdlet
4. wrapping PowerShell code into java in manner to execute it into SiteScope "Custom WMI monitor"
5. export .NET performance counter to LoadRunner

This flow seems correct but it's complicated by Citrix installed on performance test environment.

I have worked on steps 1, 2 and 3 easly and I have elaborated a correct PowerShell script that can remotelly read .NET performance counters from SiteScope server but if I execute java wrapper with PowerShell code I have found strange values.

- On some machines I see counter not realted to '_Global_' scope but related to a Citrix Service called "Health Monitor"
- On other machines I don't see any counter

In which manner Citrix can alter WMI object reading?
Why wrapping in java the working PowerShell code I cannot obtain same result?

Regards

Comment: Just a comment: you want to monitor performance using the the best know performance killers to man: Java, WMI and to a lesser extent PowerShell/.NET

Comment: I see your comment, perhaps there are some factor to be considered:
1. we can't probe on under test machine
2. SiteScope server will be well equiped
3. query rate on WMI will be greater of 5 / 10 seconds
Regards